# Error 'result::failure -9' when porting android app to BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am trying to deploy my android app from eclipse on to my blackberry Z10 running 10.0.9.422 and i am unsuccessfull at it.

Here is the actual error that i am receiving.

```
Failed to deploy project XXXX
Info: Sending request: Install
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 8659959
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 8659959 bytes
Info: Progress 0%...
Info: Progress 49%...
Info: Progress 50%...
Info: Progress 100%...
actual_dname::com.xxx.xxxx.testEPPwDTJahv0UbAeaecXksgI
actual_id::testEPPwDTJahv0UbAeaecXksgI
actual_version::1.0.3.0
result::failure -9
```

After this error, I could see the app icon on my Z10, but when i try to access it, it says' Initializing. Please wait...' and the app crashes thereafter.

What does failure -9 indicate and any idea on what's the issue/resolution might be?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix my problem after doing little research and finding the unsupported libraries for my app. I figured out the unsupported libraries using the apkbarVerifier tool.

My app was using com.google.android.maps package. So, I edited the android manifest file to reflect the below line.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false" />
```

After this change, even though the 'Verify apk' option from eclipse is showing me the same warnings, I was able to deploy the app to my Z10 and had it to work.

Basically, failure -9 on deployment means that the app contains an unsupported library.